# phoneGap C2DM not receiving ID

Tags: cordova, push, android-c2dm

Anyone try phoneGap C2DM here?   I have asked in Google group but no help.  My questions is when I run the program, it shows on my phone which means I cannot get the ID from Google.  The C2DMReceiver seems never fire.

deviceready event received
calling C2DM register, register our email with Google
C2DM->Success -> We have successfully registered and called the C2DM plugin, waiting for C2DM_Event:reistered - > REGID back from Google

Manifest

```
<permission android:name="com.phonegap.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.phonegap.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- END:C2DM messaging stuff -->

<application android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    >
  <!-- START:C2DM messaging stuff -->
    <service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />

    <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 

        <!-- Receive the actual message -->

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.phonegap.c2dm"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Receive the registration id -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.phonegap.c2dm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- END:C2DM messaging stuff -->
...
```

My case is that I combine the barcode plugin with C2DM plugin and test how 2 plugin works.  If I run C2DM plugin, it works well.  So I am sure my google id is correct

Anyone play around phoneGap C2DM, I really need your help
ALEX

Comment: Did you get this working in the end?